# Постановка запятой перед союзом "как"

Tags: пунктуация

Надо ли ставить запятую в следующем случае:"Церковь была восстановлена как храм?"

Comment: Вы, Елена, не раскроете секрет — откуда почерпнули этот «следующий случай»? Хочется надеяться, что не надпись на заборе, а относительно приличный источник навеял этот вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая не ставится: *Церковь была восстановлена **как храм.***

Здесь оборот с союзом КАК имеет значение "в качестве" (нет причинного значения или значения сравнения).
Можно сказать: Церковь была восстановлена в виде (в качестве) храма.

**Примечание:** храм и церковь различаются по предназначению, по количеству куполов и алтарей.
[**В чём различие между храмом и церковью**](http://carkva-gazeta.org/%D0%B2-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8E/)

Comment: Я думаю, речь идет о том, что церковь была восстановлена в качестве храма (а не музея, например). В широком смысле церковь - разновидность храма. Разновидности христианских сооружений (**храмов**) Русской православной церкви: часовня, церковь, храм (см "Православный храм" в Википедии)

Comment: Церковь и храм часто используются как синонимы в  одном тексте, например: Под Москвой восстановят церковь, в которой венчался Блок. ... «Нам нужен храм, восстановите его, пришлите священника» – просили местные жители. Но тогда получается, что "церковь восстановлена как церковь" (вместо "церковь восстановлена)". Нет ли тавтологии в этой фразе?

Comment: То ли хотят подчеркнуть, что восстановленная церковь будет использоваться по своему назначению (храм), то ли церковь (с одним алтарем) перешла в категорию храмов (с множеством алтарей). В любом случае фраза не очень удачно построена

Comment: На этот сайт (http://carkva-gazeta.org/) лучше не ходить, — козлёночком станешь. Белорусским, гр.-католическим. Каша, одно слово, и по части русского языка тоже.

Comment: @Sibylla В исходной фразе я не нахожу тавтологии и вижу в ней такой смысл: под церковью можно понимать архитектурное сооружение, а под храмом - место сбора прихожан и совершения религиозных обрядов. Если церковь выполняет свои прямые функции, то она является храмом. Поэтому в случае "восстановлена как храм" речь не обязательно идёт об архитектурном восстановлении: это может быть просто возобновление богослужений в заброшенной (напр. в соотв. эпоху отданной под склад) церкви, то есть восстановлена одна из важных сторон такого явления как "церковь".

Comment: А вот перефразированный вариант "церковь восстановлена в качестве храма" для меня звучит тавтологично, поскольку выражение, обычно употребляемое в значении "одно в качестве другого" начинает походить на "восстановлена в качестве самой себя". Поэтому в аргументации я отказался от привязки к значению "в качестве".

Comment: ХРАМ, 1. Здание, предназначенное для совершения богослужений и религиозных обрядов. .2. кого-чего. Высок. Х. науки ЦЕРКОВЬ, . 1. Религиозная организация ; религия, проповедуемая такой организацией. 2. Здание, в котором происходит христианское богослужение. Храм - это только здание в основном значении, а церковь имеет два основных значения. Поэтому понимать приходится согласно словарю: в общем случае как синонимы (здание для богослужения), в частном - есть различия во внешних и внутренних деталях.

Comment: О значении "в качестве". Это всего лишь искусственный прием, помогающий установить тождество и отличить его от сравнения или от обособленного приложения со значением причины. Поэтому  не стоит воспринимать это выражение как равноценную замену и анализировать на наличие или отсутствие тавтологии.

Answer (score 1):

Не надо.

Розенталь. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация, § 19 (Обособленные приложения), примечание к п. 7:

> Не обособляется и приложение с союзом как, характеризующее предмет с
>   какой-либо одной стороны: *Читающая публика успела привыкнуть к Чехову
>   как юмористу (Федин).*

http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=155#pp155